# Broken image appears when trying to select it from phpmyadmin using file path

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to select all data from my database, everything works except image, it is shown as a broken image. In my root folder I have img folder with images, and code I use for it when adding it to html is img/someimage.png

Creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`text` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`imgpath` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO `post` (`title`, `date`, `text`, `imgpath`) VALUES
('Some text.', 'img/winning-1.png');
```

Connecting to database (i have included connection.php)

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM post";
if (!$q=$mysqli->query($sql)){
echo "<p>Error</p>" . mysql_query();
exit();
}
if ($q->num_rows==0){
echo "<p>Empty!</p>";
} else {
?>
<table>

<?php
while ($red=$q->fetch_object()){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $red->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $red->date; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $red->text; ?></td>
</tr>

<img src="<?php echo $red->imgpath; ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: Can you check the view-source of your rendered HTML and see what is the URL of the image? It is possible that the database part is working correctly but something else might be messing this up.

Comment: and if you view the source html what do you get for the image path?

Comment: I get this, it should render the image, but I don't know why it doesn't
<img src="img/winning-1.png" />

Comment: Without a `/` in front of `img`, that path will be relative to the current URL, not the web root.

Comment: I have added / in front of it, but it still shows broken image.

Comment: What happens if you copy and paste `img/winning-1.png` after the host in your address bar (such as `http://example.com/img/winning-1.png`) ? What operating system is the host running? Any hints in the webserver error log? Check the permissions on the files in the "img" folder; incorrect permissions are very common problem in these situations and would cause broken images.